# Ordered TEST ON vnext build not opening the browser on Virtual Machine

Tags: tfsbuild

Im using Vnext build steps on TFS2015
Run Functional Test steps :

Test Drop Location :

```
C:\Test\Specflow.UI.PDM.Features\OrderedTests\Sanity\fix
Test Assembly : **\*.orderedtest
```

Problem : its finding 33 ordered test I have on fix folder but its running forever without opening browser on Virtual Machine

2018-06-28T09:58:16.4121163Z DistributedTests: Starting to deploy and configure test agent on test machines.

675 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Inputs provided are:

676 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Machines:

677 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Username: XXXX\XXXX

678 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Machine Group name: My Machines

679 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Run as process: True

680 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Login Automatically: True

681 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Disable Screen saver: True

682 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Agent would be downloaded from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=615472

683 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Update test agent: False

684 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Run test agent as DataCollection only : False

685 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Path to script that installs test agent on remote machine: D:\Agents\agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.21\TestAgentInstall.ps1

686 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Path to script that configures test agent on remote machine: D:\Agents\agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.21\TestAgentConfiguration.ps1

687 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Path to script that downloads test agent on azure remote machines : D:\Agents\agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.21\DownloadTestAgent.ps1

688 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.4277418Z DistributedTests: Path to script that checks if test agent is installed on remote machine: D:\Agents\agent\tasks\DeployVisualStudioTestAgent\1.0.21\CheckTestAgentInstallation.ps1

689 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.5527458Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: You may be using machine group 'My Machines' across one or more concurrent builds. This is currently not supported. Use an unique machine group per build definition and ensure there are no concurrent builds In Progress from any given build definition using a machine group.

690 
2018-06-28T09:58:16.8183793Z DistributedTests: Task 'CheckTestAgentInstallation' on machine 'XXXX:5985' is being run

691 
2018-06-28T09:58:23.0529538Z DistributedTests: Task 'CheckTestAgentInstallation' on machine 'XXXX:5985' completed.

692 
2018-06-28T09:58:23.0529538Z DistributedTests: Update test agent is disabled. Skipping test agent updates.

693 
2018-06-28T09:58:23.0685793Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'XXXX:5985' is being run

694 
2018-06-28T09:58:58.8192436Z DistributedTests: Task 'ConfigureTestAgent' on machine 'XXXX:5985' completed.

695 
2018-06-28T09:58:58.8192436Z DistributedTests: Testagents are configured and ready to run tests, make sure you use the 'Visual Studio Test using Test Agent' task in the Build Definition after this task.

696 
2018-06-28T09:58:58.8192436Z Finishing task: DeployVisualStudioTestAgent

697 
2018-06-28T09:58:58.8348686Z Starting task: Run Tests ***.orderedtest on My Machines

698 
2018-06-28T09:58:58.8348686Z Executing the powershell script: D:\Agents\agent\tasks\RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent\1.0.26\RunDistributedTests.ps1

699 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.0848686Z DistributedTests: Team foundation collection url : http://XXX:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/

700 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.0848686Z DistributedTests: Team Project : PLM

701 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: Creating run for selected test assemblies with following parameters

702 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: SourceFilter: ***.orderedtest TestCaseFilter:

703 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: Run title: TestRun_PDM Automation New Build_20180628.13

704 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: is automated: True

705 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: test machine group url : http://XXXX:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PLM/_apis/vslabs/environments/My Machines

706 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: test settings id : 3967

707 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: build location: C:\Test\Specflow.UI.PDM.Features\OrderedTests\Sanity\fix

708 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: build id: 22335

709 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.1317436Z DistributedTests: test configuration mapping:

710 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.2567436Z DistributedTests: Test Run with Id 51892 Queued

711 
2018-06-28T09:58:59.2879936Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

712 
2018-06-28T09:59:09.3036186Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

713 
2018-06-28T09:59:19.3194335Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

714 
2018-06-28T09:59:29.3352008Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

715 
2018-06-28T09:59:39.3508899Z DistributedTests: Please use this link to analyze the test run 
716 
2018-06-28T09:59:39.3508899Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

717 
2018-06-28T09:59:39.3508899Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 33, Passed Tests : 0

718 
2018-06-28T09:59:49.3509539Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

719 
2018-06-28T09:59:49.3509539Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 33, Passed Tests : 0

720 
2018-06-28T09:59:59.3667050Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

721 
2018-06-28T09:59:59.3667050Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 33, Passed Tests : 0

722 
2018-06-28T10:00:09.3827146Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

723 
2018-06-28T10:00:09.3827146Z DistributedTests: Total Tests : 33, Passed Tests : 0

724 
2018-06-28T10:00:19.3986860Z DistributedTests: Test run '51892' is in 'InProgress' state.

I tried on Command Prompt using vstest.console.exe test.orderedtest works fine but on vnext build I cant figure out where Im making mistakes or im missing something

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to manually run tests in the Virtual Machine? Did the browser opened successfully? Have you tried some other browsers, such as IE, Chrome, Edge...

Comment: IE browser working fine on my Virtual Machine and I tried manually its working fine.

Comment: If IE browser works fine, this issue should not related to TFS side, more related to your environment or browser.

Comment: even some test passing once i changed the test assembly path, running ordered test i have issue its just running ages without opening browser

Comment: I changed assembly path for ordered test and browser opened for while and then disappear, don't know where im making mistake now

Comment: following this blog ordered test working now :
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/allendm/2016/08/09/executing-ordered-tests-on-remote-machines-using-run-functional-tests-task/

Comment: Running set of ordered test its passed 2 out of 33 ordered test and i got error : QTAgent32.exe has stopped working, Problem Signature : System.OutOfMemoryException,is these error related to window updates?, even on my machine i have  got 7gb space, i can't figure out what is actual problem is?? Any help Appreciated -- Thanks